# how to automatically change the widget minwidth when the desktop layout change form 4*5 to 5*5?

Tags: android, widget

Some Android phone can adjust the desktop layout(4*5 or 5*5).
I'm developing a widget. I want it to be able to automatically change size according to the system desktop change (while system desktop:4*5 widget:4*2, while system desktop:5*5 widget:5*2).

How can do that?

Comment: Can you please post your code snippet

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml:
`</manifest>
   </application>
   ...
  <receiver android:name="com.gpl.desktop_widget.sign_manage.SignWidgetProvider"
            android:label="@string/kaoqin">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/sign_widget_provider_info" />
        </receiver>

        ...
           </application>

</manifest>`

Comment: sign_widget_provider_info.xml:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_list_style"
    android:minHeight="110dp"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/sign_widget"
    android:resizeMode="vertical|horizontal"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"></appwidget-provider>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_list_style"
     android:minHeight="110dp"
     android:minWidth="320dp"
     android:minResizeWidth="250dp"
     android:previewImage="@drawable/sign_widget"
     android:resizeMode="vertical|horizontal"
     android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
     android:widgetCategory="home_screen"></appwidget-provider>
```